# Fix the data type properties of fields when a shapefile is manipulated in R

Tags: shapefile, r, fields-attributes, dbf

I manipulated a shapefile in **R** with this code:

`d<-readOGR("RECFE.shp")
dsub<-d[d$MUNICIPIO==86,]
writeOGR(obj=dsub, dsn="data", layer="ledes", driver="ESRI Shapefile")`

In the dsub dataset some fields have not the same properties as RECFE.shp dataset. The precission of **double** fields is higher, that is, it has got more number of decimals.

       `RECFE.shp                      dsub.shp 
TYPE    LENGTH PRECISION   |    TYPE    LENGTH   PRECISION
DOUBLE   23        0       |   DOUBLE     23          15`

Is it possible to mantain the same fields properties of the old shapefile in the created new shapefile?.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible with `writeOGR` or anything else that uses `GDAL`. The `GDAL` shapefile driver has no way of specifying the precision field for floating point outputs. See http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html for details of what it *can* do.

How important is it? The "PRECISION" field for a DOUBLE doesn't affect the way the data is stored, only some aspects of its presentation. For most people its simply a nuisance! I'm also slightly confused about how you've got a DOUBLE type (xBase type O) out of `writeOGR`, mine will only create NUMERIC (xBase type N) for storing floating point data. In the xBase standard, the DOUBLE type should only be 8 byte floating point data.

You might have to resort to a separate tool if you really need to adjust these precision value, but make sure you understand the way DBF files manage their data types, because with names like DOUBLE, FLOAT, NUMERIC etc running around and often being used differently to their usual meanings it gets confusing... A good and reliable guide is here:

https://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/data_types.html

and I find the unix tools such as `dbfinfo` very handy for dumping DBF files for debugging.

Also, DBF (and hence shapefile) has some horrible limitations for numbers in terms of size and precision so this might be a chance to switch to something else...

Comment: Thanks. It is true that the precision doesn't affect but in this specific case It is better present the result without this decimals. I will read the information that you provide and if I get the process I will write it here.